# How do I get a statue to activate from a timer?

Tags: terraria

I'm trying to figure out wiring; I have the following diagram, a heart statue hooked up to a 1-second timer. The timer is on, but the statue is not activating. What's wrong with my wiring?

[image]

Comment: Are you waiting 10 seconds? The Heart Statue can only be activated once every 10 seconds. http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Heart_Statue

Comment: I waited a lot longer than that; nothing happened.

Comment: @WilliamJackson the first activation is instantaneous, you don't need to wait 10 seconds for the first heart to pop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Terraria Gamepedia page about Heart Statues](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Heart_Statue) it could be because of this:

> The statue also will not spawn a heart if there are 10 or more hearts anywhere in the world, 6 or more hearts within 800 pixels (100 blocks), or 3 or more hearts within 300 pixels (36 blocks).

Perhaps there are a few hearts somewhere underground below you?

Comment: Fighting bosses often leaves many loose hearts lying around. Save and reload to clear them.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use a 5 second timer. It worked for me.

Comment: While it's no more advantageous to use a 1-second timer than a 5-second timer, due to the 10-second minimum delay on statue activations, either timer works equally well. A 3-second timer, on the other hand, would not be recommended.